# What is a rainbow?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

What is a [rainbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow)?
I've read that an image is formed when light rays after reflection meet.
So in case of a rainbow when light ray after refraction by the water droplet reaches our eye than wouldn't that be forming the image of water droplets.

Don't the dispersed light rays form an image of water droplet?

So what we actually see as a rainbow?
Do the dispersed light rays reflect the white light which form the image of rainbow?

Comment: [Many Duplicates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=rainbow).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are many duplicates in PSE.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so light splits like it does in a rainbow when it passes through a prism such as a raindrop The reason it fans out and doesn’t just reach your eye as it normally would is because of lights wave like properties. Because white is comprised of all colors. And each of these colors (wavelengths) of light refract slightly differently. The colors fan out in order of their wavelengths.

Comment: Well sorry, I must no of understood the question. But u tried to awnser the question that I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm able to comprehend:

When visible light between (400-700) enters a raindrop normally as a spherical, physical object that allows light to pass, such as being transparent, the more transparent it is, the clearer the refraction occurs.

Because of this, it bounces off of the back of the raindrop, and if circumstances permit, if the angle is closest to 40.89–42°, the clearer the color spectrum occurs. Otherwise, the further the angle increases or decreases out of this range, the weaker the rainbow's appearance gets. This is known as incident light, whilst the light escaping the rainbow is the outgoing rays - which is a broader view of the light that entered the droplet in the first place.

As for the soft gradient in the rainbow, I believe this is caused by our atmosphere, but not too sure why, I'll find more information about it.

If we consider this in a human eye, our eyes can only see within a spectrum of approx (410-650). When the light which was refracted from the droplet (the rainbow), our retina re-constructs the light that hit our eye sensory receptor, meaning that the image is reconstructed in our visual cortex. As you said, we don't see a droplet, we see the difference of light on a droplet, such as a darker silhouette, which creates that round drop in our Visual Cortex.

Comment: A rainbow can be recorded by a camera instead of the eye. Therefore, the human eye and the visual cortex do not seem to be essential for explaining the rainbow.

Answer (score 0):

> So what we actually see as a rainbow?

We see an image of the sun in a giant mirror with a lot of chromatic aberration and a lot of spherical aberration.

However, as the round shape of the drops only steers the reflected light back in a cone shape, there is a specific angle between the sun, the drop and the observer to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

When the sun is behind the observer, a beam of light from the sun which passes close to the observer points to the center of curvature of the rainbow.  With the sun somewhat above the observer, this center will lie below the horizon. A parallel beam (at some distance to the observer)  strikes a raindrop, is refracted into the drop, reflects from the back surface, and is refracted again on leaving the drop. If this occurs in the plane of the two beams (which includes the observer) this emerging beam may reach the observer.  The angle between the emerging beam and the incident beam is called the deviation angle.  If you plot the deviation angle against the incident angle (which depends on where the incident beam hits the drop) you get a curve.  Where this curve is at a minimum, there is a range of several degrees (near 60 degrees) where all of the incident angles give the same deviation angle. This causes a concentration of light at this deviation angle, and it is this concentration that the observer sees.  Since the index of refraction varies slightly with the wavelength or color of the light, the observer sees each color at a slightly different angle (and the plane in which the angles occur can rotate around the central beam).